# Is there any sdk manager for java for sdkman for grails, groovy and gradle

Tags: java, grails, spring-boot, java-8, sdkman

Currently having issues with the current java development kit version which i am using with grails which is common when using springboot with some java 8 versions on grails

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Method
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:151)
>           ... 120 more

Is ther any sdk manager which i can use to download a specific java version which would not only download but also

1. Set current java path
2. Set current java home
3. if possible set java options

I know of update_alrenatives in ubuntu But I am talking about somwthing like gvm or sdkman

Other good options would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I use [Jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) to manage my java environment. It is easy to install and start using right away with a simple `curl` or `wget` command on Linux/Mac OS X.

```
 curl -sL https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/install.sh | bash && . ~/.jabba/jabba.sh
```

or

```
 wget -qO- https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/install.sh | bash && . ~/.jabba/jabba.sh
```

and for Windows 10 (in powershell)

```
Invoke-Expression (wget https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing).Content
```

Once this is done installing and switching jdk's is easy.

## Install

install Oracle JDK

```
jabba install 1.8
```

install Zulu OpenJDK

```
jabba install zulu@1.8.72
```

install from custom URL or file path

```
jabba install 1.8.0-custom=tgz+http://example.com/distribution.tar.gz
jabba install 1.8.0-custom=zip+file:///opt/distribution.zip
```

after each install "jabba use " will be called automatically.

## List JDK's

list all installed JDK's

```
jabba ls
```

list available JDK's

```
jabba ls-remote
```

## Switch JDK's

switch to a different version of JDK

```
jabba use 1.6.65
```

switch to the JDK specified in .jabbarc

```
jabba use
```

## Set default JDK

```
echo "1.8" > .jabbarc
```

this version will automatically be "jabba use"d every time you open up a new terminal

```
jabba alias default 1.6.65
```

jabba keeps everything under ~/.jabba (on Linux/Mac OS X) / %USERPROFILE%/.jabba (on Windows).

Answer (score 5):

You can now use `sdkman` to install and manage `java`.

`sdk install java`

http://sdkman.io/usage.html

Answer (score 2):

I use `jEnv` to manage java environment in my system.
 http://www.jenv.be/